# Using strcmp to compare strings vs. comparing characters directly

Tags: c, performance, strcmp

I am wondering if in certain situations, it would be less processor intensive to compare strings by comparing characters directly, as opposed to using strcmp.

For some background information, I am coding in C in an embedded system with not much processing power. It has to read an incoming string and do certain tasks depending on what the incoming string is.

Say the incoming string is `"BANANASingorethispartAPPLESignorethisalsoORANGES"`. I want to verify that `BANANAS`, `APPLES`, and `ORANGES` are present in their exact locations. My code would do this:

```
input = "BANANASingorethispartAPPLESignorethisalsoORANGES";
char compare[100];            //array to hold input to be compared
strncopy(compare,input,7);    //copy "BANANAS" to compare
compare[7] = "\0";            //terminate "BANANAS"
if (strcmp(compare, "BANANAS") == 0){
    strncopy(compare,input[21],6); //copy "APPLES" to compare
    compare[6] = "\0";             //terminate "APPLES"
    if(strcmp(compare,"APPLES")==0){
        //repeat for "ORANGES"
    }
}
```

Or, I could compare characters directly:

```
input = "BANANASingorethispartAPPLESignorethisalsoORANGES";
if(input[0]=='B' && input[1]=='A' && input[2]=='N' && input[3]=='A' && input[4]=='N' && input[5]=='A' && input[6]=='S'){
    if(input[21]=='A' && input[22]=="P"  <snipped> ){
        if(input[30]=='O' <snipped> ){
            //input string matches my condition!
        }
    }
}
```

Using strncopy+strcmp is more elegant, but for performance reasons, would it be faster to just compare characters directly?

Comment: I believe that `strcmp()` as `strlen()`,etc is optmized to you don't worry abou this.

Comment: If the standard-library provides you with facilities such as string-comparison, you should always prefer those.

Comment: I believe the time you've spend writing this question is far more important than the performance gain you would have from adopting the best of these two options.

Comment: Is the time required to copy a portion of an input using strncopy insignifcant? The direct character comparison doesn't need to be copied.

Comment: Note that you can do something more clever by doing a 32/64 bit int comparison: `*(uint32_t *)input == *(uint32_t *)"BANA"` checks 4 characters at once.  Most strcmps do something clever like this

Comment: standard library functions are generally best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing characters directly is pretty vile and fragile code. Depending on the compiler and architecture, it might also be harder to optimize.

On the other hand, your copy is a waste - it does nothing useful.

Just check the string is *at least* long enough (or exactly the right length, but any way not too short) and `strncmp` (or `memcmp`) it in place.

```
#define COMPARE(IN, OFF, SUB) memcmp(IN+OFF, SUB, sizeof(SUB)-1)

input = "BANANASingorethispartAPPLESignorethisalsoORANGES";

if (COMPARE(input,  0, "BANANAS") == 0 &&
    COMPARE(input, 21, "APPLES" ) == 0 &&
    COMPARE(input, 40, "ORANGES") == 0) )
{
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should better use `memcmp()` to avoid copying the data:

```
input = "BANANASingorethispartAPPLESignorethisalsoORANGES";
if (memcmp(input, "BANANAS",    7) == 0  &&
    memcmp(input+21, "APPLES",  6 ) == 0 &&
    memcmp(input+40, "ORANGES", 8 ) == 0   )
{
    // everything matches ...
}
```

At least some implementations of `memcmp()` will even be faster than comparing char by char.